# Excel matching between combination of columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have the following data on an excel :

**Sheet1 :**

```
id  effectiveDate   rateValue   CrTime
20  20130627        0.08        6/28/2013 23:05
20  20130626        0.1         6/28/2013 6:23
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
id  effectiveDate   rateValue   CrTime
20  20130630        0.08        6/30/2013 18:14
20  20130628        0.08        6/28/2013 9:38
20  20130627        0.1         6/27/2013 18:14
```

I want another 1 column on Sheet 2 which should do the following match - If there is a corresponding match in Sheet 1 for the combo of **id+effectiveDate**, then output the value.

**So expected output on Sheet 2**

```
id  effectiveDate   rateValue   CrTime             Sheet1RateValue   
20  20130630        0.08        6/30/2013 18:14      Absent
20  20130628        0.08        6/28/2013 9:38       0.08        
20  20130627        0.1         6/27/2013 18:14      0.1
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you have?  Questions which are just a list of requirements tend to get closed...

Answer (score 1):

If there concatenate of `id+effective date` is unique, `SUMIFS()` can be used instead of `VLOOKUP()` here since we're dealing with numbers.

I assume that the data are in columns A through D and starting at row 2.

```
=IF(SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,'Sheet 2'!A2,Sheet1!B:B,'Sheet 2'!B2)=0,
    "Absent",
    SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,'Sheet 2'!A2,Sheet1!B:B,'Sheet 2'!B2)
)
```

Note that you named the second sheet `Sheet 2` there instead of the default `Sheet2` (the spaces does make a difference. Change the reference as necessary.

So, this formula will sum the rates for a given `id+effective date`. If there are two similar combination of `id+effective date` in `Sheet1`, then the formula will sum the two rates. That's the difference you'll get from a vlookup.

Otherwise, if you absolutely need vlookup, I would suggest creating two helper column, one for the reference and one for the lookup, the first in `Sheet 2` and the second in `Sheet1`.

Comment: the prob. is if we have a ID of 1 and an effectiveDate 20130630         and we have an ID 2 and effectiveDate 20130629, aren't they gonna give the same, incorrect results?

Comment: @anirbanchowdhury SUMIFS() is adding the rates of cells with the same ID ***and*** same effective date. In this case, ID `1` and EffDate `20130630` will give a different result than ID `2` and EffDate `20130629`.